# Как настроить фаервол Mikrotik в качестве шлюза для двух локальных сетей?

Tags: firewall, router, mikrotik

Есть две независимые сети *192.168.10.0/24* и *192.168.20.0/24*, в каждой рабочие станции и сервера.

Возникла необходимость объединить обе сети шлюзом на *RouterOS* (*Mikrotik RB2011*). Для этого добавил два бриджа *net10* и *net20*, каждый бридж через nat выпустил в интернет. Сложность возникла с настройкой фаервола. Не получается настроить его таким образом, чтобы доступ к другой сети был только у серверов (например *192.168.10.10-15* должны иметь доступ к *192.168.20.10-15*, и наоборот), а рабочим станциям в другую сеть доступ запрещен.

Answer (score 2):

а бриджами вы случайно не объединили обе сети в один широковещательный домен?

Думаю тут надо не бриджами, а маршрутизацией работать:

1. Сделать в глобальную сеть через nat
2. Сделать правило маршрутизации в 192.168.10.*
3. Сделать правило маршрутизации в 192.168.20.*
4. В firewall в таблице FORWARD разрешить доступ c 192.168.10.10-192.168.10.15 на 192.168.20.10-192.168.20.15
5. Там же разрешить обратный трафик: с 192.168.20.10-192.168.20.15 на 192.168.10.10-192.168.10.15